# Pandoc APA Latex

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, pandoc

This may not be the right forum to ask, if not, apologies.

I am using Pandoc to convert markdown to a PDF via Latex. I am using the `citeproc-pandoc` filter to manage my bibliography. I am using APA 6 and the APA6 CSL. The filter processes the citations properly and my in-text citations are correct however the references page isn't correct - it seems like the reference page isn't being processed by the filter. Is this expected behavior? Do I need to be clarifying the bib style in the actual latex template?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you explain how the reference page is off? If you get good citations in the text I wouldn't have thought the problem is your `.bib` file? Is there a way to create a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of your file? (I realise pandoc is different from TeX, so I'm not sure what a MWE would encompass exactly.) It would be helpful if we could see the converted `.tex` file of a stripped down example as well as the commands you use to create the document.

Comment: I just noted that people have already voted to close this question. I'm not sure how pandoc-related questions are normally handled here. So I'm very much prepared to give this question the benefit of the doubt. If it turns out that the problem is a faulty CSL style or a wrong call to Pandoc, I would agree that this is off topic. But for now, I'm undecided.

Comment: Page references may need one or two runs of LaTeX before they are correct. Are you sure you make the correct number of runs? If the script uses `latexmk`, then this program will do it for you.

Comment: I broke the process down using pandoc to convert markdown to latex. This process is running as expected. If I withhold `--filter pandoc-citeproc` I get the unprocessed citation tags (`[@posluszny-jr:jbcr2003a]`). This obviously doesn't bode well when I run `pdflatex`. However, if I run pandoc with the citeproc filter I get correctly processed in-text citations (not latex cite tags, straight text `(Coffey et al., 2011)`). If I THEN run pdflatex I'm receiving this error: `Class apa6 Warning: \bibliographystyle command ignored on input line 220.` (I added `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` on line 220

Comment: This is the top of the latex doc: `\documentclass[man,noextraspace,helv,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\bibliography{/Users/rdown/Dropbox/Papers/library.bib}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking the process down is what finally worked.
This converts the in-text citations to proper latex `\cite` args and produces a latex file

```
pandoc -s --template <latex template> --biblatex input.md -o output.latex
```

Then I run that through `pdflatex` and it becomes a more latex-ey process

```
pdflatex output.latex
biber output // Per output of previous statement
pdflatex output.latex // Per output of first pdflatex run
pdflatex output.latex // Per output of 2nd pdflatex run
```

This gives me the final product with in-text citations properly formatted, the document following the template I need and properly defined reference pages.

This ended up differing a bit from my original idea; I had been trying to use the latex template and a CSL file but was running into trouble. This is a solution for PDF output, I suspect the CSL file would work for other outputs (HTML, slidly, etc)